# .htaccess redirect by adding parameter if required

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, parameters

I need to add a parameter to my current URL (but only if the paramter isn't set yet).
The other parameters should be kept (I think I can do so by adding `%{QUERY_STRING}`?).

Example:

```
index.php?page=1
```

So, let's say I want to always add a parameter for the language- the URL should look like this:

```
index.php?page=1&lang=1
```

But if `lang` is already set, it should do nothing.

Answer (score 1):

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(^|&)L=[^&]+ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(index\.php)$ $1?L=0 [L,QSA,NC,R=301]
```

Comment: +1 this should work. @MikeDoh, if you want `lang` on all pages and `page` param was only used for an example; just drop the first `RewriteCond` and you're set.

Comment: thanks for the help anubhava - but unfortunately it doesnt work like expected :(
I added a slash to make it work (in front of index\.php)

`RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(^|&)L=.+(&|$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(/index\.php)$ $1?L=0 [L,QSA,R=301]`

But it seems like it is always overwriting the other get parameters. It should just look if there is no `L` paramter and add it to the other get parameters (if there are any). Greetings, Mike

Comment: @MikeDoh: I have made an edit, try it now. Also make sure to try out in a different browser or clear your browser cache while testing.

Answer (score 0):

To do this you need to use a RewriteCond and the %{QUERY_STRING} before your RewriteRule.

It seems that you don't want to Rewrite whenever the query contains the lang parameter therefore you could use a negative RewriteCond such as:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(^|&)lang=1($|&)
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

With the above, the RewriteCond would fail when the URL already had "lang=1" therefore do not apply the following RewriteRule (which in this arbitary example simply rewrites the request to /index.php but you can tailor that to your specific needs).

Your actual rule may be different but the mechanics remain the same, use a RewriteCond and the %{QUERY_STRING}.

Hope this helps.

Comment: You misunderstood the question. OP wanted to **add** `lang=1` whenever `lang` is **not** already present. Check @anubhava 's answer for reference.